# my wordpress site only show 'error' . could not login to admin

Tags: wordpress

site only show 'error'. i have also uninstalled all the plugins from phpmyadmin
but error is still there. Could anyone help me please? [image]

Comment: you have FTP access?

Comment: Enable debug mode in wp-config.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think there is some whitespace at bottom of index.php at root. Now it is working. Thank you very much everybody.

Answer (score 3):

Please enable php errors in wp-config file.
First find wp-config file and enable debug mode set true.
After that please show me error.

Answer (score 1):

Can you print us here the log-error apache messages? 
If you use xampp you can find this file under xampp installed directory such as: \xampp\apache\logs\error.log

Comment: yes sure. it shows,  [14-Nov-2016 10:12:54 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/greathakka/public_html/GHM-LIVE/index.php on line 20

Answer (score 0):

Can you try rename plugin folder in wp-content? Maybe some plugins still not uninstalled and they had change login url.